# how to separate a dictionary item from a nested list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I am stuck in a project where I have to seperate all Dictionary item from a list and create a dataframe from that. Below is the json file link.

Link:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H76rjDEZweVGzPcziT5Z6zXqzOSmVZQd/view?usp=sharing

I had written this code which coverting the all list item into string. hence I am able to seperate them into a new list. However the collected item is not getting coverted into a dataframe. Your help will be highly appriciated.

```
     read_cont = []
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []

     for i in rjson:
for j in rjson[i]:
read_cont.append(rjson[i][j])

      data_filter = read_cont[1]
      for item in data_filter:
      for j in item:
            new_list1.append(item[j])
    
    
      new_list1 =  map(str,new_list1)
    
     for i in new_list1:
        if len(i) > 100:
             new_list2.append(i)
    
        header_names = ["STRIKE PRICE","EXPIRY","underlying", "identifier","OPENINTEREST","changeinOpenInterest","pchangeinOpenInterest", "totalTradedVolume","impliedVolatility","lastPrice","change","pChange", "totalBuyQuantity","totalSellQuantity","bidQty","bidprice","askQty","askPrice","underlyingValue"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(new_list2,columns=header_names)`
```

It should be looking something like this.........

```
Columns: [STRIKE PRICE, EXPIRY, underlying, identifier, OPENINTEREST, changeinOpenInterest, pchangeinOpenInterest, totalTradedVolume, impliedVolatility, lastPrice, change, pChange, totalBuyQuantity, totalSellQuantity, bidQty, bidprice, askQty, askPrice, underlyingValue]
Index: []
```

Comment: first put code with correct indentations - because indetations can change everything.

Comment: Fix code indentation, create [minimal reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the huge JSON file you linked to (just create a smaller one for debugging). And it's also not completely clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

h = json.load(open('scrap.json'))

mdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in h['records']['data']:
    for k in i:
        if isinstance(i[k], dict):
            df = pd.DataFrame(i[k], index=[0])
            mdf = pd.concat([mdf, df])
            continue
print(mdf)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).